# Show that the set $S$ is not a subring of $M_2(\mathbb Q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of elements $\alpha$ in the ring $M_2(\mathbb Q)$ of 2 by 2 matrices with rational entries such that $f(\alpha)=0$ for some monic polynomial $f(X)\in \mathbb Z[X]$. We want to show that $S$ is not a subring of $M_2(\mathbb Q)$. Any hint would be appreciated. Thanks!

---

**Updated**.
Consider $A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2  \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}$ and $B = \begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0  \\
1/2 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$ in $S$. (They are zeros of the characteristic polynomials $X^2-2X+1$ and $X^2+2X+1$,respectively.) Then the matrix $A+B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1/2  \\
1/2 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ has the minimal polynomial $X^2-\frac{1}{4}$ in $\Bbb Q[X]$. Probably, $A+B\notin S$ but why?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: My guess is that it is not closed under multiplication. But, I have no idea how to prove that a matrix is not root of a monic polynomial with integral coefficients. Maybe I'm missing some basic linear algebra.

Comment: If you're knowledgeable enough to ask this question, you can problably try a few things and find an answer.  Maybe keep in mind that you can assume $f$ has degree $\leq2$.  Try products of upper/lower triangular matrices with integer diagonals and non-integer off-diagonal terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After update: Your direction is correct. let $C:=A+B$. If some monic $f(X)\in \mathbb Z[X]$ has $f(C)=0$, then it is divisible by the minimal polynomial $x^2-1/4$, but then $f(1/2)=0$ contradicts to the rational root theorem.